# AWS CDK Rollback Triggers

Tags: aws-cdk

My team is working a new service on AWS and uses aws-cdk to manage our infrastructure. CloudFormation supports [using-cfn-rollback-triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-rollback-triggers.html). Is this feature supported in either CDK cli or CDK library? Is there a workaround if it's not supported by CDK other than manually updating cloudformation stacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AWS CDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk) does not currently support rollback triggers.

Usually, when a feature is missing from CDK, it can be mitigated by escaping to the `Cfn*` resources. However, rollback triggers are not represented as CloudFormation resources, but rather are configured at `create-stack/create-change-set` invocation time, and hence require support from the CDK CLI.

Long story short, unfortunately this means that there is also no workaround available.

Please feel free to [Submit a feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/new?labels=feature-request%2C%20needs-triage&template=feature-request.md), this definitely sounds like a good addition to have.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response,  found existing similar [issues - 5170](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5170)